# pandas - Going from aggregated format to long format

Tags: python, pandas

If I would go from a long format to a grouped aggregated format I would simply do:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(['a','a','a','a','b','b','c'], columns=['value'])

s.groupby('value').size()

value
a        4
b        2
c        1
dtype: int64
```

Now if I wanted to revert that aggregation and go from a grouped format to a long format, how would I go about doing that? I guess I could loop through the grouped series and repeat 'a' 4 times and 'b' 2 times etc.

Is there a better way to do this in pandas or any other Python package?

Thankful for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another and rather simple approach is to use `np.repeat` (assuming `s2` is the aggregated series):

```
In [17]: np.repeat(s2.index.values, s2.values)
Out[17]: array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)

In [18]: pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s2.index.values, s2.values), columns=['value'])
Out[18]:
  value
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     b
5     b
6     c
```

Comment: Cheers, just what I was after!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `.transform` can help with this:

```
s.set_index('value', drop=False, inplace=True)
s['size'] = s.groupby(level='value', as_index=False).transform(size)
s.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
s
```

yielding:

```
  value size
0     a    4
1     a    4
2     a    4
3     a    4
4     b    2
5     b    2
6     c    1
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be something cleaner, but here's an approach.  First, store you groupby results in a dataframe and rename the columsn.

```
agg = s.groupby('value').size().reset_index()    
agg.columns = ['key', 'count']
```

Then, build a frame with with columns that track the count for each letter.

```
counts = agg['count'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([0] * x))
counts['key'] = agg['key']

In [107]: counts
Out[107]: 
   0   1   2   3 key
0  0   0   0   0   a
1  0   0 NaN NaN   b
2  0 NaN NaN NaN   c
```

Finally, this can be melted and nulls droppeed to get your desired frame.

```
In [108]: pd.melt(counts, id_vars='key').dropna()[['key']]
Out[108]: 
  key
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   a
4   b
6   a
9   a
```